# Scikit HDBSCAN *tree* labeling (not single-slice labeling)

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, hdbscan

BLUF: For a specific epsilon (or for HDBSCAN's 'favorite' epsilon), I can extract the mapping of my data in that epsilon's partition. But how can I see my data's full tree membership?

I've gotten a ton out of the terrific tutorial [here](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_hdbscan.html). In scikit learn's HDBSCAN, I can use `clusterer.labels` to see the best epsilon's partition labels. And I can use `clusterer.single_linkage_tree_.get_clusters(0.023, min_cluster_size=2)` to see the an arbitrary epsilon's partition labels. I can even plot the entire dendogram using `clusterer.condensed_tree_.plot()`. But how do I see the dendogram's labels for individual datapoints?

For Example: It's nice that my pets' names are {Spot, Felix, Nemo, Fido, Tigger}. Or the species are {Dog, Cat, Guppy, Dog, Cat}. But I'd like one output that tells me:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Spot | Dog | Mammal | Animal |
| Felix | Cat | Mammal | Animal |
| Nemo | Guppy | Fish | Animal |
| Fido | Dog | Mammal | Animal |
| Tigger | Cat | Mammal | Animal |

With *this* sort of output, I could see precisely *how* related Spot and Felix are, instead of "Do they have the same species? Y/N?" "Do they have the same kingdom? Y/N?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`clusterer.condensed_tree_`](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdbscan.plots.CondensedTree) object has a number of conversion utilities, e.g. [`to_pandas()`](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdbscan.plots.CondensedTree.to_pandas) and [`to_networkx()`](https://hdbscan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#hdbscan.plots.CondensedTree.to_networkx). For this particular use case, it looks like you want to print an ancestor list for each leaf node in the condensed tree. You can accomplish this in many ways, but a pretty straightforward one is to convert the tree to a [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) graph and use the utility methods on it to extract the structure you're looking for:

```py
import hdbscan
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

# run HDBSCAN
data = np.load('clusterable_data.npy')
clusterer = hdbscan.HDBSCAN(min_cluster_size=15).fit(data)

# convert tree to networkx graph
tree = clusterer.condensed_tree_.to_networkx()
assert nx.algorithms.tree.recognition.is_tree(tree)

# find the root by picking an arbitrary node and walking up
root = 0
while True:
    try:
        root = next(tree.predecessors(root))
    except StopIteration:
        break

# create the ancestor list for each data point
all_ancestors = []
for leaf_node in range(len(data)):
    ancestors = nx.shortest_path(tree, source=root, target=leaf_node)[::-1]
    all_ancestors.append(ancestors)
```

Printing `all_ancestors` will give you something like:

```
[[0, 2324, 2319, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [1, 2319, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [2, 2319, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [3, 2333, 2324, 2319, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [4, 2324, 2319, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [5, 2334, 2332, 2324, 2319, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 ...
 [995, 2309],
 [996, 2318, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [997, 2318, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [998, 2318, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 [999, 2318, 2317, 2312, 2311, 2309],
 ...]
```

The first entry in each list is the node ID (corresponding to the index of the node in in the `data` array), the second entry is that node's parent, and so on up to the root (which, in this case, has the ID 2309). Note that any node ID greater than the number of data items that you have is a "cluster node" (i.e. an inner node of the tree), and any lower node ID is a "data point node" (i.e. a leaf node in the tree).

It may be slightly easier to understand this list format by sorting the nodes into their clusters, e.g. with:

```py
all_ancestors.sort(key=lambda path: path[1:])
```

Printing `all_ancestors` now will give you something like:

```
[[21, 2309],
 [126, 2309],
 [152, 2309],
 [155, 2309],
 [156, 2309],
 [172, 2309],
 ...
 [1912, 2313, 2311, 2309],
 [1982, 2313, 2311, 2309],
 [2014, 2313, 2311, 2309],
 [2028, 2313, 2311, 2309],
 [2071, 2313, 2311, 2309],
 ...
 [1577, 2337, 2314, 2310, 2309],
 [1585, 2337, 2314, 2310, 2309],
 [1591, 2337, 2314, 2310, 2309],
 [1910, 2337, 2314, 2310, 2309],
 [2188, 2337, 2314, 2310, 2309]]
```

There are many equivalent ways to get the same result (e.g. by looping over the pandas dataframe produces by `to_pandas()`), but `networkx` is a natural choice for pretty much anything you might want to do with trees/DAGs/graphs.

Comment: Terrific! Thanks for the reply and welcome to StackOverflow!

How do you know that `leaf_node in range(len(data))` and `target=leave_node` corresponds to the original index of the data? I thought e.g. some data elements aren't included in the tree at all (if they're "outliers") so there wouldn't even be as many leaves as there are data.

(Obviously my complaint is moot, since your code clearly works. :) But how did you know 'target' could just be 'data_index'.?)

Comment: From the `to_pandas()` docs linked above: "The parent and child are the ids of the parent and child nodes in the tree. Node ids less than the number of points in the original dataset represent individual points, while ids greater than the number of points are clusters." -- this combined with looking at how the `to_networkx()` code works (by looping over the dataframe and adding nodes to the graph) was how I got that the indexes were used as the node IDs, so I could just loop over the indexes to find the path to the root for every data item.